# Celery: Unable to detect the tasks

Tags: python, docker, celery

I am working on `python` web app in which I am using `celery` to process long running tasks. I have docker-compose setup and following is project structure as below:

```
proj/
  - __init__.py
  - docker-compose.yml
  - web/  # web app
  - celery_app.py # contain celery instance
  - tasks/
       - __init__.py
       - foo
           - __init__.py
           - foo_task_one.py # imported celery instance
           - foo_task_two.py # imported celery instance
           - foo_task_three.py # imported celery instance
       - bar
           - __init__.py
           - bar_task_one.py # imported celery instance
           - bar_task_two.py # imported celery instance
           - bar_task_three.py # imported celery instance
```

I am using following command to start celery worker as below:

```
command: ["celery", "--app=proj.tasks.foo", "worker", "--queues=foo", "--pool=prefork", "--concurrency=1", "--loglevel=INFO"]
```

I am getting error as it is unable to load all foo's tasks

```
Error: Invalid value for '-A' / '--app': 
Unable to load celery application.
'proj.tasks.foo' has no attribute 'celery'
```

But When I specifically specify a particular task it runs successfully, below is command

```
command: ["celery", "--app=proj.tasks.foo.foo_task_one", "worker", "--queues=foo", "--pool=prefork", "--concurrency=1", "--loglevel=INFO"]
```

How can I load all foo's tasks, what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has more to do with how python imports work than celery. As you are specifying, `--app` as `proj.tasks.foo`, celery looks for Celery object instance inside files `proj/tasks/foo/__init__.py` or `proj/tasks/foo.py`. As it didn't find any Celery object inside any of those files, it threw exception. But when you specify `proj.tasks.foo.foo_task_one`, it checked inside `proj/tasks/foo/foo_task_one.py`, it found an app instance(imported from celery_app) and used it to start the worker.

For all of your tasks to be visible and run by celery you can use the proxy `current_app` inside each of your task files and import those task files in a common file, which you can then use as input to the `--app`.

```
# foo_task_one.py
from celery import current_app
....


@current_app.task()
def _task_one_def():
   pass
```

```
# foo_task_two.py
from celery import current_app
....

@current_app.task()
def _task_tow_def():
    pass
```

```
# tasks/foo/__init__.py
from celery_app import app
from . import foo_task_one, foo_task_two
```

And you can use the same command to start the worker inside worker. Internally, celery `current_app` proxy gets resolved to app instance during runtime.

```
command: ["celery", "--app=proj.tasks.foo", "worker", "--queues=foo", "--pool=prefork", "--concurrency=1", "--loglevel=INFO"]
```

Comment: Hi Lemon, Thanks for detail explanation. Earlier, I did tried importing all tasks inside `foo __init__.py` but did not imported `celery_app` module explicitly. Now after importing it got no errors and ran successfully.